# rearrage lines of file in unix

Tags: perl, unix

**I have a file with the below format. This is a snippet, original lines cross over a million.**

Infact **ABC/DEF/GH9j/etc..** is the starting of a line and **";"** is supposed to be the end of the line.

Here in this example **line01, line10 & line13** are perfect; But other lines are scattered in to multiple lines:

line01:      **ABC** *abc_123* ( .Y ( B2b ) , .A ( sel ) );

line02:      **DEF** *def_456* ( .Z ( n_2 ) , .in ( 1b0 ) ,

line03:                           .tstin ( sel ) , .tstmb ( DD ) );

line04:      **GH9j** *3_inst* ( .Q0 ( CC3 ) , .Q1 ( Ee ) ,

line05:                               .Q2 ( p_2 ) , .Q3 ( cin ) ,

line06:                           .D0 ( AA ) , .D1 ( rdata[5] ) ,

line07:                           .D2 ( gg ) , .D3 ( hp ) ,

line08:                               .SE0 ( sel ) , .SE1 ( sel ) ,

line09:                               .SE2 ( pqr ) , .SE3 ( AA ) , .CK ( Bb ) );

line10:      **BUF** *4PQR* ( .Y ( eE ) , .A ( cC ) );

line11:      **MX2** *MnOp* ( .X ( DD ) , .A ( PQR_11 ) ,

line12:                     .B ( trstb ) , .S0 ( klm2 ) );

line13:      **BUFH** *6th_inst* ( .Zz ( AA ) , .A ( B2B ) );

.......

**Q. I want to rearrange all lines like below: 
All the ports of one instance should be in ONE LINE (13 lines should reduce to 6 lines)**

line01:      **ABC** *abc_123* ( .Y ( B2b ) , .A ( sel ) )**;**

line02:      **DEF** *def_456* ( .Z ( n_2 ) , .in ( 1b0 ) , .tstin ( sel ) , .tstmb ( DD ) )**;**

line03:      **GH9j** *3_inst* ( .Q0 ( CC3 ) , .Q1 ( Ee ) , .Q2 ( p_2 ) , .Q3 ( cin ) , .D0 ( AA ) , .D1 ( rdata[5] ) , .D2 ( gg ) , .D3 ( hp ) , .SE0 ( sel ) , .SE1 ( sel ) , .SE2 ( pqr ) , .SE3 ( AA ) , .CK ( Bb ) )**;**

line04:      **BUF** *4PQR* ( .Y ( eE ) , .A ( cC ) )**;**

line05:      **MX2** *MnOp* ( .X ( DD ) , .A ( PQR_11 ) , .B ( trstb ) , .S0 ( klm2 ) )**;**

line06:      **BUFH** *6th_inst* ( .Zz ( AA ) , .A ( B2B ) )**;**

Comment: This seems a bit simple ... is this all the transformation you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner might work: `perl -pe' chomp unless m/\;/' file.txt` -  though with millions of lines some tweaking might be needed.

Here is the one liner as a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp unless m/\;/ ;
    print ;
}

__DATA__
ABC abc_123 ( .Y ( B2b ) , .A ( sel ) );
DEF def_456 ( .Z ( n_2 ) , .in ( 1b0 ) ,
.tstin ( sel ) , .tstmb ( DD ) );
GH9j 3_inst ( .Q0 ( CC3 ) , .Q1 ( Ee ) ,
.Q2 ( p_2 ) , .Q3 ( cin ) ,
.D0 ( AA ) , .D1 ( rdata[5] ) ,
.D2 ( gg ) , .D3 ( hp ) ,
.SE0 ( sel ) , .SE1 ( sel ) ,
.SE2 ( pqr ) , .SE3 ( AA ) , .CK ( Bb ) );
BUF 4PQR ( .Y ( eE ) , .A ( cC ) );
MX2 MnOp ( .X ( DD ) , .A ( PQR_11 ) , 
.B ( trstb ) , .S0 ( klm2 ) );
BUFH 6th_inst ( .Zz ( AA ) , .A ( B2B ) );
```

**Output:**

```
ABC abc_123 ( .Y ( B2b ) , .A ( sel ) );
DEF def_456 ( .Z ( n_2 ) , .in ( 1b0 ) ,.tstin ( sel ) , .tstmb ( DD ) );
GH9j 3_inst ( .Q0 ( CC3 ) , .Q1 ( Ee ) ,.Q2 ( p_2 ) , .Q3 ( cin ) ,.D0 ( AA ) , .D1 (  rdata[5] ) ,.D2 ( gg ) , .D3 ( hp ) ,.SE0 ( sel ) , .SE1 ( sel ) ,.SE2 ( pqr ) , .SE3 ( AA ) , .CK ( Bb ) );
BUF 4PQR ( .Y ( eE ) , .A ( cC ) );
MX2 MnOp ( .X ( DD ) , .A ( PQR_11 ) ,.B ( trstb ) , .S0 ( klm2 ) );
BUFH 6th_inst ( .Zz ( AA ) , .A ( B2B ) );
```

If you need to preserve the line numbers (`line01:`) add a note to that effect in the question.

Comment: no need to escape ; in a regex (though it doesn't hurt to do so)

Comment: also, -p implies -n; you don't need both

Comment: thanks `-n` was typo leftover (fixed) but I did not know about `\;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sed solution:

```
sed -n 'H;/;/{s/.*//;x;s/\n//g;p;}' filename
```

Comment: oops I didn't see the unix part of the question and thought there must be some missing bit of array/hash munging. I'd be curious to see if `perl -npE' chomp unless m/\;/' file.txt` was as fast as `sed` on 1 million lines.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your whole dataset, or at least large chuncks of it, its hard to know what pattern to match on, however in the example you give, it seems as though the lines you want to merge end in a ,newline therefore simply changing ,newline to , might do the trick:

```
sed -e ':begin;$!N;s/,\n/,/;tbegin;P;D' in.txt
```

outputs:

```
ABC abc_123 ( .Y ( B2b) , .A ( sel));
DEF def_456 ( .Z ( n_2) , .in ( 1b0) ,.tstin ( sel) , .tstmb ( DD));
GH9j 3_inst ( .Q0 ( CC3) , .Q1 ( Ee) ,.Q2 ( p_2) , .Q3 ( cin) ,.D0 ( AA) , .D1 ( rdata [5]) ,.D2 ( gg) , .D3 ( hp) ,.SE0 ( sel) , .SE1 ( sel) ,.SE2 ( pqr) , .SE3 ( AA) , .CK ( Bb));
BUF 4PQR ( .Y ( eE) , .A ( cC));
MX2 MnOp ( .X ( DD) , .A ( PQR_11) ,.B ( trstb) , .S0 ( klm2));
BUFH 6th_inst ( .Zz ( AA) , .A ( B2B));
```

See http://backreference.org/2009/12/23/how-to-match-newlines-in-sed/ for more details on matching newlines in sed.

Comment: Am I wrong that this only works with GNU `sed` (Linux) and not POSIX `sed` (BSD, OS/X, etc.)?  The `perl` one liner is portable :-)  +1 for reference.

Comment: @G.Cito that's a good point and I'm not familiar enough with non gnu sed's to know the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner in AWK

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, /;\s*$/ ? "\n" : " "}' filename
```

It outputs each line with a separator that is either a newline or space depending on whether `;` is found at the end of the line.